# Original answers

Tags: discussion, citing-sources

If an answer is the conclusion of a user, not overtly sourced, but the sources it is developed from are sourced, is it appropriate/necessary to point out that the conclusion is unsourced?

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely.

The more information you can give about the conclusion(s) in your answer (who made them, when they made them, what led them there, etc.) the better. It's hard for me to imagine how extra information can hurt.

Comment: I think your "absolutely" applies to "appropriate" and not to "necessary", right?  That is, we want people to provide this information, but we're not going to delete answers that fail to do so.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I agree with this answer, and I'd even say such information is necessary, not in the sense that the answer can't exist without it, but in the sense that one should definitely include it (it's not just a nice extra).

Comment: Ok, if "necessary" means "...to be a good answer (e.g. worthy of an upvote)" then we're on the same page.  Versus "...in order to exist", which I think is not what we're saying.